# Error in finding xpath for a sub-element in HTML

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am using below code

```
Actions action=new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(facultyOfCivil).build().perform();
WebElement oceanManagement=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='https://www.annauniv.edu/iom/home.php']"));
action.moveToElement(oceanManagement).build().perform();
oceanManagement.click();
```

After hovering the mouse on an element, i am not able to find xpath for sub-element as the sub-element is not being displayed in HTML

Answer (score 0):

Use `JavaScriptExecutor` to click the element. Try this one,

```
WebDriverWait webDriverWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

Actions actions = new Actions(webDriver);
actions.moveToElement(facultyOfCivil).build().perform();

WebElement oceanManagement = webDriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id="menuItemHilite32"]")));
((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", oceanManagement);
((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", oceanManagement);
```

Comment: thanks Harsitha, but still not working ,, even xpath is not displying for subelement, so thats why i am using href

Comment: Can you post the website and also image of the element. So we can help you.

Comment: http://annauniv.edu/ - click on department-> Faculty Of Civil Engineering" and click on "Institute for Ocean Management"

Comment: `//*[@id="menuItemHilite32"]` Did you try with this as xpath?

Comment: You can find this by going inspect element in the browser. Check [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jSiYpmvA50A).

Comment: i tried updated code also but still it is not clicking, just hovering the mouse on faculty of civil engineering after that it is not clicking on Institute of Ocean management

Comment: Thanks Hasitha,, i changed the id =menuitem32 , now its working

Comment: That's great. So you used `By.id` instead of `By.xpath`?

Comment: i used xpath only but i saw three elements are displying in html for that object so i used 
 first element  id=menuitem32